# How to install FreeBSD on Thinkpad?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, thinkpad

I am trying to install FreeBSD but I am having a problem.  My computer is a Thinkpad T400.

I followed the instructions to install so I have downloaded the file `FreeBSD-8.3-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso` and burned the ISO image to disc.

When I boot with the disc it comes to the Welcome to FreeBSD screen. But when I choose option 1 for Boot FreeBSD [default] nothing happens - it just stays stuck at the welcome screen like it is frozen.

Like in the instructions I tried to disable ACPI in the BIOS but I cannot find any option to do this. The closest I found is CPU Power Management which I disabled anyway. I also tried selecting option 2 - Boot FreeBSD with ACPI disabled - but nothing happens. All it does is stay stuck on the welcome screen.

I know the install disk is OK because it boots on my desktop computer (I abort the install). How do I install it on my Thinkpad?

Answer (score 4):

I've run into a similar situation, so you're you need to either turn off ACPI or switch to an integrated video card only so the installation can continue.

Also, there's [compatibility list](http://laptop.bsdgroup.de/freebsd/index.html?action=list_laptop_mf&mfid=154) you may check, you may submit your own as well.

Comment: Switching to integrated video worked and I am able to continue the installation.  Thank you very much.